# Turn off auto indent in sublime text 2, but

Tags: coldfusion, indentation, sublimetext

Right now in sublime text 2 when I start an if statement in Coldfusion and hit enter it will automatically indent the next line like this:

```
    <cfif this eq that>
        |
```

When I turn auto indent off it will leave the cursor back at the far left, which would be great, but a lot of times my code is already indented:

```
    <cfif this eq that>
|
```

What I want is it to leave it where it is currently indented to, no more, no less. Like this:

```
    <cfif this eq that>
    |
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: I think you want to keep `auto_indent` on, and turn `smart_indent` *off* - http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/indentation.html

Comment: 1. I don't type my if statements like that, i finish off the <cfelse> and </cfif> first. 2. It does this for every coldfusion tag, even ones that are 1 line, such as <cfargument> or <cfparam>. It just gets annoying.

Comment: I posted an answer to similar question here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11297868/sublime-text-v-2-0-how-do-i-stop-auto-indentation-on-new-lines-after-bracket/13756901#13756901

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be other ways to make this work for you.
But, you can edit the regex string in ColdFusion.tmPreferences file under

```
<key>increaseIndentPattern</key>
```

Just add cfif and cfelse to the list

```
|link|meta|param|cfif|cfelse
```

When there is an update to the ColdFusion package though, you may have to edit again.

**Edit**: Make sure to update the package to the latest version. The single line tags like cfargument should not indent as expected in the updated version.

Answer (score 0):

Although what you would like does not seem to be possible at the moment, see [ST2 forum](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5692&p=25331&hilit=indent#p25331) (maybe you posted that?)

A slightly absurd workaround that may work for you, (seems to work for me). Go to `View>Syntax>Java` now the auto indention should do as you please - you may lose bracket tag matching (+other things?), syntax checking may be a bit nuts (you can always flip back if necessary, try other syntax stuff), and the colour scheme will change a little, but it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the settings in Sublime, there is one called 'smart_indent'.

The description for this setting is:

> Makes auto indent a little smarter, e.g., by indenting the next line
>   after an if statement in C. Requires auto_indent to be enabled.

Found some more info in the [Sublime Documentation](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/indentation.html).