# Sublime Text (v 2.0) - how do I stop auto indentation on new lines after brackets?

Tags: sublimetext2, indentation, auto-indent

I'm trying to make the jump from Notepad++ to Sublime Text 2. However one issue is stopping me from doing so:

When working in CSS, JavaScript or PHP - whenever I type a bracket and press [ENTER], an extra indentation is added. E.g. below show's you where the caret ends up if I type a bracket and press enter:

```
    {
        |
```

I need the caret to appear at the same horizontal point as the bracket, like so:

```
    {
    |
```

I've tried messing with the indentation settings to no avail. Here are my current User Settings:

```
{
"auto_indent": true,
"auto_match_enabled": false,
"bold_folder_labels": true,
"color_scheme": "Packages/Color Scheme - Default/Twilight.tmTheme",
"detect_indentation": false,
"font_face": "Courier New",
"font_size": 10,
"highlight_modified_tabs": true,
"ignored_packages":
[
    "Vintage"
],
"indent_to_bracket": false,
"line_padding_bottom": 1,
"line_padding_top": 1,
"smart_indent": false,
"trim_automatic_white_space": false
}
```

UPDATE: if I set **auto_indent** to **false**, this creates a different problem. In this case, the caret will always be placed at the very beginning of the line. E.g.

```
        {
|
```

I've also tried playing with the files in Packages/JavaScript to no avail.

Would really appreciate a solution as I really want to start using this editor!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Change the value for `auto_indent` to `false`. That'll fix it for you!

Comment: Thanks but this creates a different problem. In this case, after pressing ENTER, the caret will always be placed at the very beginning of the line (see above for code example).

Comment: @Danny Connell - ah.. I see..hmm, i'll have a think!

Answer (score 1):

I found that if you use SHIFT+Enter you get what you want.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent "smart" indentation or automatic next/extra level indentation in e.g. Ruby you need to edit the `%AppData%\Sublime Text 2\Packages\Ruby\Miscellaneous.tmPreferences` file, not the `%AppData%\Sublime Text 2\Packages\Default\Indentation Rules.tmPreferences` file, despite of presence of settings like `increaseIndentPattern` in both. That is, editing the latter (commenting out the tag insides, for example) won't take any effect. Valid for version 2.0.1.